# Is it a good idea to keep track of online users in a database table or in memory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am trying to decide whether or not I want to keep track of my online users in a database table or just in memory.  In memory seems much easier to me and makes sense because if the server is restarted, I would have to truncate the table everytime the system starts up.  Also each user on my system can add contacts  (other users) and everytime a user signs on I get the list of users that he or she is friends with and send a signalR message to them that the user is online.  So for something like this I feel like getting the data from memory will be much faster, but don't what will happen when I decide to scale out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to add more servers to your production environment you will need to keep Session in the database and as a result your list of online users will need to be in the database so that it can be shared across all servers.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  [Please note that signatures or salutations should not be added to your posts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 3):

> for something like this I feel like getting the data from memory will be much faster

Premature optimization being the root of all evil, I would encourage you to keep the information in the database and retrieve it as needed. Then you can run metrics and make changes if the number of online users begins to present performance problems.

Comment: +1. Write code that produces results you want first, consider optimizations later. Note that it is very hard to predict which exact problems such distributed system in *your case* will have without implementing it at least once.

Answer (score 0):

If you start to scale out you'll need to share this information between servers anyway, so I'd put it in the database right from the beginning. [JabbR](http://jabbr.net), which is a reference application for SignalR, also does this so it can't be too bad.